# Using Code in SP2013 sandbox solutions

Tags: 2013, sandbox-solution

I inherited a sandbox solution deployed to an SP2013 and I am currently struggeling to add a new feature version.

Somewhere I read that sandbox solutions are no longer soupported in 2013 - but I could not find any official statement on that.
The only nearly-official statement I found was on [http://blogs.msdn.com/](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions.aspx) stating that no-code sandboxed solutions are still supported in 2013.

Does that mean that feature-receivers and upgrade-action-receivers are no longer possible for sandbox solutions in 2013?

Somehow I am unable to deploy even the simplest sandbox solution if I added a feature-receiver.

Comment: I guess in SP2013 only no code sandbox solutions are supported. below is the link where it is written that "Sandboxed solutions that contain only declarative markup and JavaScript — which we call no-code sandboxed solutions (NCSS) — is still viable, we have deprecated the use of custom managed code within the sandboxed solution" http://davidlozzi.com/2013/09/12/sharepoint-2013-sandbox-solutions-declarative-or-user-code-whats-dead-really/

Comment: @Amit: Yes. That's my guess, too. But I much rather have it verified.

Comment: the blog that i have shared contains a lot many references of technet/msdn (But i guess they haven't mentioned it very clearly). If you go throw the MSDN article you will see that MVP's are also discussing about the same. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2013/08/01/sharepoint-sandbox-isn-t-dead-usercode-is.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developing sandboxed solutions that contain only declarative markup and JavaScript -- which we call no-code sandboxed solutions (NCSS) -- is still viable,  the use of custom managed code within the sandboxed solution is  deprecated. They have introduced the new SharePoint app model as a replacement to those scenarios that required the use of managed code. The app model decouples the SharePoint core product from the app runtime, and this enables much more flexibility and gives you the ability to run the code in the environment of your choice.

Official blog :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions.aspx

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13154.sharepoint-2013-sandboxed-solutions-are-deprecated.aspx

EDIT:

As far as I know, sandbox solutions with code still work in on-premises and are blocked in SharePoint Online.

Comment: WOOPS! Meant to edit my own post, sorry!

Comment: Some people don't give much value to the msdn blogs (even if their official, I guess) so I linked the technet article instead.

Answer (score 0):

Official text on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj163114.aspx

Emphasis mine:

> While developing sandboxed solutions that contain **only declarative markup and JavaScript -- which we call no-code sandboxed solutions (NCSS)-- is still viable**, we have **deprecated the use of custom managed code** within the sandboxed solution. We have introduced the new SharePoint app model as a replacement to those scenarios that required the use of managed code. The app model decouples the SharePoint core product from the app runtime, and this enables much more flexibility and gives you the ability to run the code in the environment of your choice. We realize that our customers have made investments in coded sandboxed solutions and we will phase them out responsibly. Existing coded sandboxed solutions will continue to work in on-premise SharePoint farms for the foreseeable future. Given the dynamic nature of online services, we will determine support needs for coded sandboxed solutions in SharePoint Online based on customer demand. NCSSs continue to be supported. All future investments will go to making the new SharePoint app model richer and more powerful. Accordingly, we recommend that all new development should use the new app model whenever possible. In scenarios where you have to develop a farm solution or coded sandboxed solution, we recommend that you design it so that it can easily evolve toward a more loosely coupled development model.

The way I read this :

- Sandbox Solutions with code: Deprecated
- Sandbox Solutions with only declaritive items: Allowed (NOT deprecated)
- Apps: Recommended

EDIT:

As far as I know, sandbox solutions with code still work in on-premises and are blocked in SharePoint Online.